# Matrix direct product retaining indices in python

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

I am a novice programmer starting to code in python. I have two 2D numpy arrays which I want to combine to form a 4D numpy array in the following manner,
    `array_4d[i, j, k, l] = array_1[i, j] * array_2[k, l]`
I can of course brute force this by writing nested for loops, but I want to know is there more efficient way to do this and if this operation is already predefined in some package. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you had a look at [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)? It allows you to write this down quite elegantly:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.random_integers(0,9, (2,2))
>>> b = np.random.random_integers(0,9, (3,3))
>>> c = np.einsum('ij,kl-> ijkl', a, b)
>>> a
array([[4, 5],
       [8, 0]])
>>> b
array([[6, 8, 4],
       [8, 5, 5],
       [8, 9, 8]])
>>> c
array([[[[24, 32, 16],
         [32, 20, 20],
         [32, 36, 32]],

        [[30, 40, 20],
         [40, 25, 25],
         [40, 45, 40]]],


       [[[48, 64, 32],
         [64, 40, 40],
         [64, 72, 64]],

        [[ 0,  0,  0],
         [ 0,  0,  0],
         [ 0,  0,  0]]]])
```

The loops will be in C, so this is fast.

This particular product can also easily by made with numpy's broadcasting:

```
>>> c2 = a[...,np.newaxis, np.newaxis]*b
>>> np.any(c2-c)
False  # indicates that both approaches result in the same ndarray
```

This latter approach turns out to be even faster, but be aware that timing results often depend on the input arrays:

```
In [61]: a = np.random.random_integers(0,9, (20,30))

In [62]: b = np.random.random_integers(0,9, (300,500))

In [63]: %timeit c2 = a[...,np.newaxis, np.newaxis]*b
1 loops, best of 3: 250 ms per loop

In [64]: %timeit c = np.einsum('ij,kl-> ijkl', a, b)
1 loops, best of 3: 342 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks that is brilliant! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: @user231042 you should accept the answer.  [Answerer will get points and *you* will get points](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)! Win Win!